# how to only show order success page once with React - redirect or empty page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a novice with ReactJS so I may be missing something obvious here. I currently have an issue where users can refresh the order success page on my site and it will consistently be rendered (this causes issues with duplicate tracking in e.g GA), where instead it should only be allowed to be displayed once, then if refreshed, I want to redirect them to another page (it's not important where, homepage is fine). The main thing is just to ensure that the success page can only be rendered once.

I've been trying to handle this via `componentWillUnmount`, but I can't seem to force the redirect to happen, so possibly it's not the right place to handle it. Here's where I've got to.

I've also tried to add a check for the `successShown` state to the `render` method, so that if it was true, it shouldn't render the content. I'm aware I'm probably veering off the path I should be taking for handling this type of situation, so I'd be grateful for any help.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class OrderSuccessContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            successShown: false,
        };
    }
    
    componentWillMount() {

        if (this.state.successShown) {
            window.location = '/test.html';
        }

        let orderId = this.props.match.params.orderId;

        // The order ID is in the URL so on a refresh this will always match unless it's flushed

        if (!orderId) {
            window.location = this.redirectHome();
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.state.successShown) {
            window.location = this.redirectHome();
        }
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.componentCleanup);
    }

    componentCleanup = () => {
       
        // Set success shown to true now that we know the page has been shown
        this.setState({successShown: true});
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.componentCleanup();
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.componentCleanup); // remove the event handler for normal unmounting
    }

    render() {
     // This doesn't work, always generates the page
      if (this.state.successShown) return null;
        return (
            <div>
                <!-- All the success content here -->
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This would be easier to read if you made your example more minimal by removing the all the `console.log` statements.  Also, you shouldn't be handling all this redirect logic like this.  React is meant to be used in a more declarative fashion.  If you need routes, take a look at https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router.

Comment: @jmargolisvt - fair comment, i've removed the console statements and anything not related. I'm not hell bent on using a redirect, more so just a way of ensuring the success page can't be rendered more than once - whether this is handled via a redirect, or by flushing the content on the page, I'd be happy with either.

Comment: If you want to store a flag that says the user has seen this screen, it needs to be outside the component somehow.  Otherwise you end up right where you are, trying to compare and preserve state.  Normally, I'd store the flag in Redux state, but you could use also localStorage or sessionStorage to get you by.